# Hosted MySql, Views, client Ipaddress change and Access Denied

Tags: mysql, view, access-denied, heidisql

I have a hosted MySql server with many databases each with many views.  I access the server remotely from my office using `HeidiSql`.

Once in a while the IP address of my office changes.  When this happens, I have to add the new office IP address to the server using cPanel and the "Remote MySql" tool so that I can remotely connect again.

However, all of the views have definer: `USER@OLD_IP_ADDRESS`.  If I need to change a view, I get `Access Denied`.  Up to now, I have been deleting the view (yes, i can delete the view) and recreating it, which makes the view's definer `USER@NEW_IP_ADDRESS`, and then I can edit the view -- until the Ip address changes again.

So, my question is: What is the best practice is an environment like this.  Is there a way to define the views once and, without causing a security risk, be able to edit the views after an IP Address change.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loosen the host in the MySQL user account a bit, according to the IP range of your internet provider. That way, you don't need to change it every time you get a slightly different IP:

```
user@123.456.789.%
user@123.456.%
```

This of course loosens the security in this account, but if your password is be a good one, it should not be too risky.

A better way is to make the MySQL server only accessible via SSH. In that case, your MySQL server can be set up using the [--skip-networking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) option, as you always connecting from localhost. Your user account can be user@localhost or user@127.0.0.1, which then would solve your above mentioned problem for all times.

HeidiSQL also supports SSH tunneled MySQL connections, see [here](http://www.heidisql.com/help.php#connecting) for some tutorial.